# jQuery : a drag-and-drop upload with multi dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, drag-and-drop, treeview

I want to develop a tree of folders and files with a drag-and-drop upload on folders.

Example:

[image]

For the drag-and-drop upload, I fund [**jQuery File Upload**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

The basic code is:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'php/index.php',
    dropZone: $(document),
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
```

In my project, I've multi dropzone (my folders) like for example :

```
<ul>
    <li>Bookmarks</li>
    <li>Search</li>
    <li>Web dev</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

**How to change the code above to handle the multi dropzone with id, class and jQuery selectors?**

---

I tried something like this but obviously it doesn't work:

```
<ul>
    <li id="folder1" class="folder">Bookmarks</li>
    <li id="folder2" class="folder">Search</li>
    <li id="folder3" class="folder">Web dev</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

.

```
$('.folder').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'php/index.php',
    dropZone: $('.folder'),
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text($(this).attr(id)).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
```

**Issues:**

- the upload is done 3 times.
- $(this) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution with a colleague.

Actually it wasn't complicated:

```
    $('.folder').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'php/index.php',
            dropZone: $this,
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text($this.attr('id')).appendTo(document.body);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Edit: My bad, this answer was in [the documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Upload-Widgets-on-the-same-page).